# Why does standard deviation equal ~16 for these values: 150, 170, 190 and not 20?

Tags: statistics

The mean value is 170. If I understand standard deviation correctly it's +/- *some value* and in this case, it's 16. But 170 + 16 doesn't equal 190. Why is that? Shouldn't standard deviation be 20?

Comment: This is a good page for standard deviation https://www.mathsisfun.com/data/standard-deviation.html

Comment: Definitions are your friends.  The standard deviation has a formula, easily found in Wikipedia or other sites, so research for that definition before asking here.  Perhaps you are using a classroom text?

Comment: It depends on whether you use $\sqrt{\frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^{N}(x_i-\mu)^2}$ or $\sqrt{\frac{1}{N-1}\sum_{i=1}^{N}(x_i-\bar{x})^2}$.  The second of these will give $20$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The standard deviation can roughly be thought of as a kind of average deviation from the mean (Not exactly though!)  Now 150 deviates from the mean by 170 by 20. 190 also deviates from 170 by 20. But don't forget that 170 itself is also a data point, and 170 deviates from 170 by 0. So, between those 3 numbers, the 'average deviation' will be below 20.  Now, like I said, it is actually not the average of those deviations, for that would be 13.33, but we have our reasons for not just taking the average of the deviations, but using the squares of those. Anyway, the point remains: don't forget about 170 itself!

Comment: Didn't think about 170 as another data point. Now I see that for 150 and 190 stdev is 20. Thank you for clarification :)

Comment: @Delyew You're welcome! :)

Answer (score 1):

The standard deviation is just over $16$. Why? You do the calculation
and that's what pops out.

If the random variable was equally likely to be 150 or 190 (and nothing else) then the standard deviation would be 20.
But it is equally likely to be 150, 190 or 170. That 170 pushes the
standard deviation down a bit, so we shouldn't be surprised at
it being a bit under 20.

Answer (score 0):

The formula for stdev is $$\sigma=\sqrt{\frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^{N}(x_i-\mu)^2}$$ where $\mu$ is $\displaystyle \frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^{N}x_i$. In your case $x_1=150,x_2=170,x_3=190$, hence $\mu=170$ and $$\sigma=\sqrt{\frac{1}{3}\left((150-170)^2+(170-170)^2+(190-170)^2\right)}=\sqrt{\frac{800}{3}}=16.322$$